# How to retrieve more than 10 results using yql in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, yahoo, yql

```
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' +encodeURIComponent( query ) + '&format=xml&callback=?';

    $.getJSON( yql,function( data ){

        if(data.results[ 0 ]) {

             var garageName = "";
             for(var counter = 0; counter < data.results.length; counter++ ){
                garageName = garageName + data.results[counter];
             }
             console.log(garageName);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `&format=json` so you can fetch it using jsonp

Comment: @NULL from a website html. not from a database. can i use &format=json?

Comment: @user3378168 You will get response like this 

[Yahoo APIs](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fplus.google.com%2Flocal%2FIndonesia%2Fs%2Fcar%2520service%20%22%20and%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fa%5B%40class%3D%27d-s%20ob%20ob%20e7%20Sza%20VFa%27%5D%22&format=json&callback=)

Comment: @ranganadh indeed. but i want to retrieve more than 10 results. how to do it ?

Comment: @user3378168 Have you looked at the response from the `yql` url?

Comment: @NULL i just get that yql url from online example. and i just copy and paste.